# React, fetch data from database before rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have problems with `useState` and `useEffect`. Here is the code:

```
const [words, setWords] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    getAllData()
  }, [])

async function getAllData(category){

    let url = `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/improve-language`

    let response = await fetch(url)
    let data = await response.json()
    let result = await data

    await setWords(result)
  }
```

I expect from `useEffect` to get data from api and set to `useState` variable. And then I'm going to use that `useState` variable anyway. But, when the website load, I see that `useState` variable is `null`, after when I writing a new code line and saving the file, then I see that `useState` variable has the data finally.

I need to get the data before the website rendering procces. I need to have the data when the page loads. Otherwise, I'm getting errors.

**Update:** Thanks to everyone who answered to question. Everyone says "use a loader" but I'm already using it. But the main problem is not this.

There are lots of functions and useState variables. And I need the data immediately to make other functions and useState variables to useable.

I'm aldreay using loading effect, but the main problem is functions needs words variable which works for make datas to useable and to present to user.

I need that data after using the setWords(data) function which is in getAllData() function.

I need datas before everything.

Comment: Show all of your code please, particularly your return statement

Answer (score 2):

Rather then creating a async function inside the functional hook, you can create a function inside useEffect which gets called on component mount and display a loading spinner when data is being fetched.
This is my approach for the above problem statement

```
const LoadingDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`

const [words, setWords] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  const getAllData = async() => {
    let url = `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/improve-language`;
    let response = await fetch(url)
    let data = await response.json()
    setWords(data)
  };
  getAllData();
}, [])

return (
  words ?
  <YourComponents.../> : <LoadingDiv > Loading... < /LoadingDiv>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using more `await` than it is needed. That has been said, you can use some loading component while you are fetching the data (it is the recommended way), like so :

```js
const [words, setWords] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    getAllData()
  }, [])

async function getAllData(category){

    let url = `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/improve-language`

    let response = await fetch(url)
    let data = await response.json()
    setWords(data)
  }
  
  if(!words){
    return <p>Loadin ...</p>
  }
```

Comment: Okay, I already have a loading spinner. And it's works greate. But, the function works at the start. If words variable is null, then it will never has the data. Because words variable is a bridge. Not the main variable. I'm writing another variable to the screen by using words variable. That's why, if words variable is null, then main variable always waits null like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is that you would display a loading spinner until you have data in `words`. That way, the page will load, your spinner will show until theres data, then when data is in you can remove the spinner and actually display your content

Comment: I already have a loading spinner but words variable is not the main variable. I'm writing another variable to screen, if words variable is null, then other variable will be null forever. I need to make fulled to words variable with datas at the beggining. And then everyting will works great.

Answer (score 0):

The component is going to render right away, and the process of fetching data is asynchronous.  Instead of trying to make the browser wait to render the component, just *handle the null case* for the data.  For example, in your rendering:

```
return (
  words ?
    <YourComponents ... /> :
    null
);
```

This would render nothing (because it returns `null`) if `words` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), and will render the JSX markup after the state has been updated to include the data you need.

You can likely improve this by adding some kind of "loading" indicator instead of just returning `null`.  But if, as specified in the question, you want to simply not render anything then `null` would accomplish that.

Comment: If I do like this then I never see the data because the functions only works at the begining. If I click a button then the functions works again but, to click that button I need to see datas before. I think, I need a controller. If `setWords()` worked and `words` variable has the data then no problem, otherwhise re-run the functions after 1-2 secons...?